# Why is this epistemic logic situation valid

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, modal-logic

So this is epistemic logic and as far as I know this is similar to predicate logic so that is the reason for  tagging this this  way.

[image]

So I can see that $p$ is indeed true in worlds $w,s$, but I don't see this for the other statements. Like I agree partly with "$\square p$ is true precisely in worlds $w,u,s$" But I don't see why $v$ is different to $u$. They both have a knowledge relation to $s$ and they both have $\neg p$ but $u$ has knowledge of $p$ and $u$ does not?

This is example 5.26 in [this pdf](http://www.logicinaction.org/docs/lia.pdf#page=158). (page 158)

Comment: Where is the image taken from? This doesn't appear to describe an epistemic accessibility relation, but a more general kind of Kirpke frame.

Comment: (The major case of it not being an epistemic frame being that the statements about what's true make perfect sense if only $w$ can access itself, and one doesn't typically draw a loop at only one world if the relation is intended to be reflexive.)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine [here is the page in the pdf I have](http://www.logicinaction.org/docs/lia.pdf#page=158) (158). I don't see how the  knowledge relation on w impacts the relations v->s and u->s where u is said to be knowledgeable of p but v isn't

Comment: The point here is not that $w$ is accessible to itself, it's that $v$ and $u$ are *not* accessible to themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram doesn't depict an epistemic Kripke frame, which are always required to be reflexive. Note that in the document you take this from, the following comes immediately before this diagram:

> Now let us also look at a much more abstract example, that does not admit an epistemic
>   interpretation. This will allow you to see how our mechanism of interpretation works in
>   the more general case.

So this is clearly intended not to be an instance of an epistemic Kripke frame.

In the depicted frame, neither $u$ nor $v$ are accessible to themselves, so the $\bar{p}$'s occurring in $u$ or $v$ respectively don't affect the truth of any modal statements at those worlds. In particular, the only world accessible to $u$ is $s$, where $p$ holds, so $\square p$ holds in $u$. However, $v$ can access $u$, where $\bar{p}$ does hold, so clearly $p$ does not hold at *every* world accessible from $v$, and $\square p$ thus doesn't hold in $v$.

Comment: I did not know of the name kripke frame and will be looking into it more. Thank you for your answer. I now see that the relation between v->u is a contradiction to the knowledge p by v->s and as such $\box p$ is not true for all relations of v. Do you suppose that $\diamondp$ would be correct for v?

Comment: Yes, $\diamond p$ does hold at $v$, thanks to the world $w$. It's also a good exercise to sort out what sorts of things are true at $s$, since this is by far the weirdest one in the diagram.

Comment: For s being an odd one, the next page says that some notation "characterizes endpoints in the accessibility relation" and it being applicable to s. Isn't it actually weird that $\square p$ holds at s, as the knowledge relations aren't reflexive. As you noted the diagram wouldn't normally otherwise only denote a reflexive relation on w.

Comment: The tricky thing about $s$ is $\square p$ isn't true because $p$ is true in $s$, but because *anything* with $\square$ in front is true in $s$; the next page points out that even $\square\bot$ holds in $s$, even though $\bot$ is never true at any world. The reason for this is that statements that universally quantify over an empty set ("for all worlds accessible to $s$...") are always true.

Comment: ooohh I would've never connected set theory to this scenario but that matches their wording in Definition 5.24 completely. But that would mean that if s was reflexive then then it would be $\square p$ and $\square \neg q$ in s. And now without that reflexivity $\square q$ is also true for s.